# Using maven to build an CXF & Spring Web Service EAR file for Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: spring, maven, weblogic, cxf

I have created a simple CXF & Spring web service and successfully build a war file using maven. Now I need to package this web service to an EAR file and deploy it on a remote weblogic server.

I have tried searching the web regarding how to using maven to build an EAR file for the CXF & Spring web service but not much information.

Does anyone have done this before and able to share how can I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: would this help? http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-Packwarinanear%2Cdeploytheearwithweblogicapplication.xml

Comment: I saw this but I also need to configure to pom.xml to build the ear file for weblogic server. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [maven-ear-plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) cover a lot of this.  The WebLogic specific part is to decide what kind of [production redeployment strategy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13702/redeploy.htm#DEPGD258) will be used.  If the plan is to use "production redeployment" then there is an additional entry to make in the ear manifest so WebLogic has version information for the application (more [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13706/versioning.htm#WLPRG239)).  Here's an example partial POM.

```
<groupId>com.company.maven.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>myEarSimple</artifactId>
<version>${my.ear.version}</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>myAppEar</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>5</version>  <!-- Java EE version used by the app -->
                <displayName>${project.artifactId}</displayName>
                <applicationName>${project.artifactId}</applicationName>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>

                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <!-- Must have this if you intend to use production redeployment, use whatever value you like as long as it conforms to WebLogic's version criteria specified in documentation provided -->
                        <Weblogic-Application-Version>${project.version}</Weblogic-Application-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <moduleId>myWebAppId</moduleId>
                        <groupId>com.company.maven.sample</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myWar</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>myWarContextRoot</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <moduleId>myEjbId</moduleId>
                        <groupId>com.company.maven.sample</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myEjb</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <!-- other modules here -->
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Here, you specify dependencies corresponding to the modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.maven.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>myWar</artifactId>
        <version>${the.war.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.maven.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>myEjb</artifactId>
        <version>${my.ejb.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to built the EAR file and deployed to weblogic successfully but now i have another problem. Weblogic doesn't seems to recongised the web service. When I expand the tree in weblogic admin console, this is wat I see:

HelloWorldWS
+Modules
++ HelloWorld (Web Application)
+EJBs
++ None to display
+Web Services
++ None to display

Could it be my CXF and Spring Configuration?

Comment: I've never done this with web services.  In theory it shouldn't matter what kind of module you're deploying in the ear.  I recommend checking the WebLogic logs to make sure all modules of the ear deployed correctly.  Did you make sure the data sources, JNDI, etc. that your app needs were configured correctly?

Comment: Currently it's just a simple hello world web service. No database connection.

Comment: I managed to get the web service up and running. Thanks for all your help. =]